# How to determine a measure out of a positive linear functional

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

let $X=[-2,2]$. $l$ is a positive linear functional on $C([-2,2])$ such that $l(x^{2n})=C_{2n+2}^{n+1}$ and $l(x^{2n+1})=0$ can we determine the measure corresponding to this positive linear functional?

Comment: [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Moments) may help